# How to Get Data Join Django Rest Framework

Tags: mysql, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to join two tables,
i have model :

Employee :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_identity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    place_birth = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    no_hp = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employee'
```

Penalty :

```
class Penalty(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    doc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'penalty'
```

My EmployeeSerializer :

```
class EmployeeSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:  
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

My PenaltySerializer:

```
class PenaltySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Penalty
        fields = ('employee','type','start_date','end_date')
```

My expected Penalty result :

```
"results": [
        {
            "employee": 14871,
            "type": "low",
            "start_date": "2018-10-15",
            "end_date": "2018-10-16",
            "employee_identity": "A1738129",
            "full_name": "Full name here",
            "role": "staff"
           
        }
    ]
```

I have tried to using this in my serializer

```
class PenaltySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
 a = EmployeeSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Penalty
            fields = ('employee','type','start_date','end_date','a')
```

but the result of 'a' not showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help

```
class PenaltySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
        employee_identity = serializers.CharField(source="employee.employee_identity")
         full_name = serializers.CharField(source="employee.full_name")
         role = serializers.CharField(source="employee.role")

        class Meta:
            model = Penalty
            fields = (
                    'employee',
                    'type',
                    'start_date',
                    'end_date', 
                   'employee_identity',
                   'full_name',
                   'role'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your serializer:

```py
class PenaltySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model=Penalty
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_employee(self, object):
        return EmployeeSerializer(object.employee.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: I got error "The field 'employee' was declared on serializer PenaltySerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option."

Comment: try adding fields values separately including the employee field.

Comment: oke i try change fields with fields = '__all__' and now error 'Employee' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: you can't do 'all', you should do '__all__'. Or alternatively, you should add each field separately, as you did on your question.

Comment: same error, i add each field separately but got error 'Employee' object has no attribute 'all'